# SQL Express 2012 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I have a project of that uses Spring, Hibernate and supports MySQL and SQL Server. However one test which works fine on MySQL, but fails on SQL Server Express 2012. 
All other tests work well SQL server. I have pasted exception log below (replacing project specific values with xxxx)
I have verified that the row in question {idUni=1,id=4} exists in database and that this is a unit test so realistically I expect only 1 thread to be accessing this object at any given time. Appreciate any hints at fixing this.

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [xxxxx] with identifier [xxxx {idUni=1,id=4}]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [xxxx#xxxx {idUni=1,id=4}]
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:485)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855)
>       at xxxx.persistence.GeneralDAO.merge(GeneralDAO.java:100)
>       at xxxx.persistence.HasGeneratedCompositeIdDAO.merge(HasGeneratedCompositeIdDAO.java:108)
>       at xxxx.persistence.HasGeneratedCompositeIdDAO.merge(HasGeneratedCompositeIdDAO.java:11)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.merge(Unknown Source)
>       at xxxx.persistence.xxxxx.testModifyTask(xxxxx.java:171)

Classes

```
public abstract class HasGeneratedCompositeIdDAO<T extends HasGeneratedCompositeId, Identifier extends GeneratedCompositeId>    extends GeneralDAO<T, Identifier>
    implements IHasGeneratedCompositeIdDAO<T, Identifier> {
......
    @Override
    public T merge(final T detachedInstance) {
        GeneratedCompositeId compId = detachedInstance.getId();
        if (compId == null || compId.getIdUni() == 0)
            throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("mergeWithMissingIdUni");
        return super.merge(detachedInstance);
    }

......
}
public abstract class GeneralDAO<T extends Serializable, Identifier extends Serializable> implements IGeneralDAO<T, Identifier> {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
......
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T merge(final T detachedInstance) {
        return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(detachedInstance);
 }
......
}
```

Datasource properties

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.x.x:1433;databaseName=xxx" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
```

==============================================

Did more testing and found that the error is thrown due to entity version mismatch. When I run the tests against MySQL the source (detached) and target both have version value of 0. While when I run the same test against MS SQL server the source has version 0 and target has version 1.

Also The code is running using JDK 1.7 and JRE source and target are at level 1.6

I tried moving the JDK, JRE source and target to 1.8 and tested with MS SQl server JDBC driver 6.0 and still got the same error.

Comment: Could you provide your daos/repositories, hibernateutil and so on?

Comment: Added some relevant snippets. the code belongs to a client so can't add any more details here. Appreciate any hints

Comment: did you take the object from DB? Are you using the sring transactional support?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Yes transaction support is on. And the object in database does not get udpated.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata misread your question, No the 'detachedInstance' was created directly in memory and not taken from DB.

Comment: Try to fetch it from db

Comment: Fetch from db and then setting data followed by save definitely works. 
The only problem is that I have an test involving the merge that works on MySQL and fails on SQL Server.

Comment: After a lot of debugging I found the real reason behind the exception was that my detached instance (created in memory) had a different version number (0) as compared to one in database . The version number difference only seemed to be showing up in the SQL server tests, but not on MySQL, which is still a mystery. However I got the version from the database copy and then explicitly set it on the detached copy and that seemed to work